Freeipa backup questions
I'm trying to decide whether Freeipa is the way to go, or whether it introduces too much complexity for a small business (~25 client PCs, mostly Linux). Freeipa is  actually a delight for day-to-day ID management operations, so the question revolves around backup/ restore and disaster recovery.
If I run ipa-backup on the master ipa server daily, and save a VM snapshot less frequently (always after freeipa version upgrade, +monthly? it's a few Gb), is that always going to suffice? Do the replica servers need backing up at all?
Come to that,  do I even need to worry about backup, with an ipa first server and two replicas physically separate? Anything that takes out all of them would be a "fire/flood" event that would probably require restoration of all company on-site data from off-site, and IT would be the least of the problems in any case. What lesser disaster would utilize a full ipa-backup?
I've seen references to server snapshots being "too old" and being "outside the replication window". Can anybody tell me how long this is? Also whether restoring a snapshot and then updating it with the most recent ipa-backup would avoid this problem?
(I have to say, I wish that they could come up with something as simple as NIS, which sat there for two decades and "just worked". But of course, its desperately insecure against anyone malevolent with access to the LAN).

FreeIPA recommends snapshots over backup restore, which are described as experimental. Recovery with loss of one server or everything is fairly straightforward. Data loss recoveries or recovering into an environment where something is left and needs to be reconciled is a bit more interesting. I doubt many have done it. https://www.freeipa.org/page/Backup_and_Restore

It does no harm to run ipa-backup and save the result but having multiple replicas largely covers against a server failing. If you run FreeIPA on VMs (which seems to be recommended), snapshots and backups of the VM volume may provide an easier form to restore from. A ZFS volume is especially idea for this purpose.

This is mostly a comment but space is limited.

If I run ipa-backup on the master ipa server daily, and save a VM snapshot less frequently

Sounds like you might consider reviewing the tools you use for backup up the VM if there is any benefit to backing up just the IPA data compared with the whole vm.

do I even need to worry about backup, with an ipa first server and two replicas physically separate?

Do you know how to promote a replica to master? How often do you test this? Are the replicas offsite? Even if you have good answers to these, then the answer is probably no. If your infrastructure is hacked then you can't trust the online replicas (although in such a scenario you're also going to be replacing all the secrets in IPA).

snapshots being "too old" and being "outside the replication window". Can anybody tell me how long this is?

No. You didn't tell us how the snapshots were being created / managed.

The reason not to back up the VM often is that its around 1000 times larger than the ipa-backup. Although if 4Gb once a month will do, it's not a major issue. As for how, what I've done in the past is stop the VM and copy the qcow2 file and associated metadata elsewhere. But the stuff about "outside the (unspecified) replication window" worries me. I might test a VM backup today and restore next week and it works, and then when disaster strikes, find it is somehow expired.

....you are doing it wrong. Get a proper backup solution which handles de-duplication (like Veeam, borg, PBS) and stop using cpio/tar.

@symvbean To be useful the backup has to be stored off-site. A freeipa backup contains key security secrets so the backup  has to be encrypted. How does de-duplication help?

Try it. After all you should never relay on any backup solution until you've tested it.
